# Swift Initialize struct based on typealias

Tags: swift, generics

I want my code to be as reusable as it can be. `Writer` and `JsonProperties` are Protocols that define plenty of the functionality the related objects require. `JsonProperties` conforms to `Codable` protocol, but I want to implement a custom method for Core Data implementation, through a `Writer`, the question is:

Can I initialize an object that implements a `Writer` protocol through the typealias of `JsonProperties`?

Right now I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Model]' to expected argument type '[Model.WriterType.Model]'

Here's the code:

```
protocol Writer {
    associatedtype Model: JsonProperties
    ...
    init(in dataStack: DataStack)
}

struct GenericWriter<Model: JsonProperties>: Writer { ... }

protocol JsonProperties: Codable {
    associatedtype WriterType: Writer
    ...
}

struct ConversationProperties: JsonProperties {
    typealias WriterType = GenericWriter<Self>
    ...

}
```

The implementation I was looking for, but got the error was:

```
func networkFetch<Model: JsonProperties>(type: Model.Type) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> {
    let writer = Model.WriterType(in: dataStack)
    ...
    var objects = [Model]()
    ...
    writer.insert(objects) <- Error here!
```

My guess this is not the correct implementation of the `init()` of a `typealias` struct.

Comment: @Sweeper The insert method was implement in the Writer protocol and its inheritance.

Comment: `Json` is considered to be spelled wrong in Swift. (See [follow case conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're seeing stems from the fact that you not haven't constrained the associate type `WriterType` within `JsonProperties`.

Currently, it accepts any `WriterType` type conforming to `Writer`, regardless of what its `Model` is.

What you probably want is for the `WriterType` type to have its `Model` be the same as the type being conformed to `JsonProperties` protocol - so you need to constrain it:

```
protocol JsonProperties: Codable {
    associatedtype WriterType: Writer where WriterType.Model == Self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `insert` method accepts a `[Model]`, where `Model` is the associated type of `Writer`.

`writer` is of type `Model.WriterType` where `WriterType` is a `Writer`, so `writer.insert` accepts `Model.WriterType.Model`. Here, the first `Model` is the generic parameter of `networkFetch`, whereas the second `Model` is the associated type of the `Writer` protocol.

However, you have created a `[Model]`. This `Model` refers to the generic parameter of `networkFetch`, not the associated type.

There is actually no guarantee that your generic parameter `Model` is the same type as `Model.WriterTypeModel.Model`. For example, I could do:

```
struct FooProperties: JsonProperties {
    typealias WriterType = GenericWriter<ConversationProperties>
}
```

And if I pass `FooProperties.self` to `networkFetch`, the generic parameter `Model` would be `FooProperties`, but `Model.WriterType.Model` would be `ConversationProperties`.

There are many ways to fix this.

1. You can constrain the `WriterType` associated type to forbid me from creating a `FooProperties` in the first place:

```
protocol JsonProperties: Codable {
    associatedtype WriterType: Writer where WriterType.Model == Self
}
```

2. You can constraint the generic parameter `Model`:

```
func networkFetch<Model: JsonProperties>(type: Model.Type) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error>
    where Model.WriterType.Model == Model {
```

3. You can create an array of `Model.WriterType.Model` instead (this will not work if you are deserialising objects of type `Model` and putting them into this array)

```
var objects = [Model.WriterType.Model]()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was really clear, and strait forward.